# I have a warning on all of my posts on my page after I updated my theme

Tags: html, wordpress

I have just updated my theme and the following error occurs:

> Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in /home/itsallab/public_html/wp-content/themes/covernews/lib/breadcrumb-trail/inc/breadcrumbs.php on line 254

On this line of the file it writes :

```
:sprintf('<a href="'.esc_url( $link_item ).'" itemprop="item">%s</a>', $item );
```

What part could cause this error?

Comment: It is possibly caused by the languge settings. Please take a look at to following link to see the possible solutions.https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-sprintf-too-few-arguments-5/

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation and `sprintf` should not been combined in a single line. Try using the following:

```
sprintf('<a href="%s" itemprop="item">%s</a>', esc_url( $link_item ), $item );
```

Comment: doesnt work it says "SYNTAX error , unexpected T_STRING"

Comment: I forgot a semicolon `;`, could you try it again? As it is cleaner then combining concatenation and sprintf? @user3668903

Answer (score 0):

i found the resolution. it had two '' more that needed in here "'.esc_url( $link_item ).'"
dont know why after the update it changed but i